# Issue running python script

Tags: python

I'm running a python script called ALPS which installs packages. It has worked, but now spits this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/alps", line 295, in <module>
    initPackages()
  File "/usr/bin/alps", line 156, in initPackages
    packageMap[line.split(':')[0]].append(line.split(':')[1].strip())
KeyError: 'gnome-icon-theme'
```

The error occured when I made spelling mistake with the package 'gnome-icon-theme?

This is obviously linked to python, but can anyone point the way to solving this?  The source code can be found here: https://github.com/FluidIdeas/alps

thanks

Cliff

Comment: How are you running this command?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm running from a terminal after chrooting into the new system I'm building.  The error ocurs here but also happens in the new system from a terminal as one would expect.  The command looks like:  'alps install r -p gnome-icon-theme-extras'

Comment: Right so it seems that the error exists because the key doesn't exist.  But why is the program failing from then on, following the error.  It's just not usable following the mistake.